# is_home() not working in functions.php file

Tags: functions, hooks, conditional-tags

I'm using woo themes and trying to use some woo hooks to hook into the index.php file from my child theme.

I'm using the following code:

```
function content_woo_main_before() {
    if  (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
        include('includes/home-news.php');
    }
};
add_action('woo_main_before', 'content_woo_main_before', 15 );

function content_woo_main_after() {
    if  (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
        include('includes/home-news-after.php');
    }
};
add_action('woo_main_after', 'content_woo_main_after', 15 );
```

The strange thing about this is that the first function loads as it should on the home page, but the second one does not. I tried a few things like changing the order that the functions are run, changing the names, I tried wrapping the functions in the conditional statement. Nothing worked.

Am I doing something wrong here?

I found a few other posts that had something similar to this, about how the `is_home()` won't work in functions.php, because it runs before we know if we're on the home page, but that wouldn't explain why the first function works properly, and the second one doesn't.

Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

So, based on the feedback I've gotten, I've updated the following using `get_template_part()`

http://www.re-electsusanguidry.com/admin/

here's the code:

```
function content_woo_main_before() {
    echo 'is_home1 =' . is_home();
    echo 'is_front_page1 = ' .  is_front_page();

    if  (is_home()) {
        get_template_part('home', 'news');
    }
};
add_action('woo_main_before', 'content_woo_main_before', 20 );



function content_woo_main_after() {
    echo 'is_home2 = ' . is_home() . '<br />';
    echo 'is_front_page2 = ' .  is_front_page();
    if  (is_front_page()) {
        echo 'is_home3 =' . is_home();
        echo 'is_front_page3 = ' .  is_front_page();
        get_template_part('home', 'after');
    }
};
add_action('woo_main_after', 'content_woo_main_after', 21 );
```

Here's what I don't get. If I have both of these functions with both using `is_home() || is_front_page()`, the first returns "1", but the second functions return nothing at all. So, "is_home1" returns 1, "is_front_page1" returns 1, therefore it's true and the content loads. However, "is_home2" and "is_front_page2" returns nothing, the conditional statement returns false, and the content doesn't load.

I tried various numbers for the loading sequence, but that didn't do anything. I 
put some crazy long number and it still didn't return true.

What's also weird is that if I take out the first function (woo_main_before), the second one works as expected. Only when both of them are there does the second one not work.

I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem online. I have no idea what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php`? And also make sure that something is not wrong with file `home-news-after.php` than the `home-news.php`.

Comment: Try to debug using `echo is_home()` and `echo is_front_page()` for home page and other page. Hope this will help you to resolve the issue. Also enable debug.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use get_template_part() instead of your `include()` Also I'd make sure you're not having a priority conflict. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: I thought about the priority conflict too. I had one set as 16, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam, debug is on, but it's only giving me one error that has to do with something unrelated (at least I think). Also, there is only a few closing divs on that page. No PHP or any other code that would cause the page to not load.

Comment: @BandonRandon I've modified this to use  `get_template_part()`, but it doesn't seem to be working still.

Comment: you can also use  the  bloginfo('siteurl');  for the  front page   and  is_front_page()  also   or other one  get_option('home');  and many other on wordpress codex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the first hook function, which contained a query needed a reset.

Adding `wp_reset_query();` after the initial query has fixed the issue.